# if {...} else {...} : Does the line break between "}" and "else" really matters?

Tags: r, if-statement

I write my `if {...} else {...}` statement in R in the following way as I find it more readable.

```
Testifelse = function(number1)
{
     if(number1>1 & number1<=5)
     {
          number1 =1
     }
     else if ((number1>5 & number1 < 10))
     {
          number1 =2
     }
     else
     {
          number1 =3
     }

     return(number1)
}
```

According to `?Control`:

> ... In particular, you should not have a newline between `}` and `else` to avoid a syntax error in entering a `if ... else` construct at the keyboard or via source ...

the function above will cause syntax error, but actually it works! What's going on here?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The documentation at `?Control` recommends against it, although the circumstances where it can cause problems are relatively rare.

Comment: btw `switch` may prove useful when you have many cases

Comment: You really shouldn't change the question once you've started receiving answers.  Having code in a function versus running it in the console changes things quite a bit.  Answerers do not receive notification when an edit has been made to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Original question and answer**

If we put in R console:

```
if (1 > 0) {
  cat("1\n");
  }
else {
  cat("0\n");
  }
```

why does it not work?

**R is an interpreted language, so R code is parsed line by line.** *(Remark by @JohnColeman: This judgement is too broad. Any modern interpreter does some parsing, and an interpreted language like Python has no problem analogous to R's problem here. It is a design decision that the makers of R made, but it wasn't a decision that was forced on them in virtue of the fact that it is interpreted (though doubtless it made the interpreter somewhat easier to write)*.)

Since

```
if (1 > 0) {
  cat("1\n");
  }
```

makes a complete, legal statement, the parser will treat it as a complete code block. Then, the following

```
else {
  cat("0\n");
  }
```

will run into error, as it is seen as a new code block, while there is no control statement starting with `else`.

Therefore, we really should do:

```
if (1 > 0) {
  cat("1\n");
  } else {
  cat("0\n");
  }
```

so that the parser will have no difficulty in identifying them as a whole block.

In compiled language like C, there is no such issue. Because at compilation time, the compiler can "see" all lines of your code.

---

**Final update related to what's going on inside a function**

There is really no magic here! The key is the use of `{}` to manually indicate a code block. We all know that in R,

```
{statement_1; statement_2; ...; statement_n;}
```

is treated as a single expression, whose value is `statement_n`.

Now, let's do:

```
{
  if (1 > 0) {
    cat("1\n");
    }
  else {
    cat("0\n");
    }
}
```

It works and prints `1`.

Here, the outer `{}` is a hint to the parser that everything inside is a single expression, so parsing and interpreting should not terminate till reaching the final `}`. This is exactly what happens in a function, as a function body has `{}`.

Comment: Thanks! 
?Control says the following:

Note that it is a common mistake to forget to put braces ({ .. }) around your statements, e.g., after if(..) or for(....). In particular, you should not have a newline between } and else to avoid a syntax error in entering a if ... else construct at the keyboard or via source. For that reason, one (somewhat extreme) attitude of defensive programming is to always use braces, e.g., for if clauses.

This indicates that we should be fine with brackets on their own line except for the else statement. I ran few tests on my end and it seems to the case

Comment: This is true enough (so +1), but "R is an interpreted language, so R code is parsed line by line" doesn't quite follow. Any modern interpreter does *some* parsing, and an interpreted language like Python has no problem analogous to R's problem here. It is a design decision that the makers of R made, but it wasn't a decision that was *forced* on them in virtue of the fact that it is interpreted (though doubtless it made the interpreter somewhat easier to write).

Comment: If you use the code I posted in my question, you will realized that if you use the debugger you do not run into any issue. Any explanations would be welcomed.