# Recursive peasants algorithm in R leads to infinite recursion

Tags: r

I was trying to implement this following python function in R. Here the main function is calling within the function.

## recursive edition of Russian peasants algorithms

```
def rec_russian(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        return 0
    if a % 2 == 0:
        return 2 * rec_russian(a/2, b)
    return b + 2 * rec_russian((a-1)/2, b)
```

## The R representation of the function

```
rec_russian <- function(a, b) {  
  if(a == 0) {        
    return(0)
    } else {
    a %% 2 == 0
    return(2 * rec_russian(a/2,b))
    }
  return(b + 2 * rec_russian((a-1)/2,b))
  }

rec_russian(3,4)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to do:

```
rec_russian <- function( a , b ){
  if( a == 0 ){
    return(0)
    } else if (a %% 2 == 0) {
    return( 2*rec_russian(a/2,b) )
    } else {
    return( b + 2*rec_russian((a-1)/2,b))
    }
}
rec_russian(3,4)
# 12
```

Have a read on `?Control` for control statement in R.

Also related is this post: [if {…} else {…} : Does the line break between “}” and “else” really matters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37929184/4891738) and my answer there. And you will learn that you can also write

```
rec_russian <- function( a , b ){
  if( a == 0 ){
    return(0)
    }
  else if (a %% 2 == 0) {
    return( 2*rec_russian(a/2,b) )
    }
  else {
    return( b + 2*rec_russian((a-1)/2,b))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It was very detailed!

Answer (score 3):

```
rec_russian <- function( a , b ){

   if( a == 0 ) return(0)

   if (a %% 2 == 0) return ( 2*rec_russian(a/2,b) )

   return ( b + 2*rec_russian((a-1)/2,b))
}
rec_russian(3,4)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I never used "if" statement as you have done. So it's a good learning from your answer. But I marked Li's answer as correct, because he put in details where I was making the mistake. Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: My code is direct translation of the python code at hand. You can use if statements without an else, which I did in this case. It makes sense to do so here because `return` terminates the function, and if any of the if conditions are satisfied the function halts there, so you can omit the `else`s