# R - Writing a function to return binary output using if statement

Tags: r

Good day,

I am a beginner and trying to understand why I am getting the error below.

I am trying to create a function that would return 0 or 1 based on column values in data set.

```
LT = function(Lost.time) {
    For (i in 1:dim(df)) {
        if (df$Lost.time > 0) {
            x = 1
        }
        else {
            x = 0
        }
        return(x)
    }
}
```

Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level In addition: Warning
     message: In if (df$Lost.time > 0) { : the condition has length > 1 and only 
   the first element will be used> } Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes in the code:

1. R is case sensitive. Use `for` instead of `For`.
2. If you are looping over the entries in `df$Lost.time`, the individual elements should be addressed within the loop using `df$Lost.time[i]`. However, a loop is not necessary for this task.
3. An `else` statement should not begin on a new line of the code. The parser cannot know that the `if` statement is not finished after the first block. If the `else` statement is enclosed in curly braces like in `} else {` there will be no problem in this sense.
4. The parameter passed to the function is not suitable. Maybe you could pass `df`, instead of `Lost.time`, but it may be necessary to rewrite parts of the function.
5. The use of `1:dim(df)` in the `for` loop should work, but it will trigger a warning message. It is better to use `1:nrow(df)`.

Those are syntax problems. However, the main issue is probably what has been addressed in the answer by @TimBiegeleisen: In the loop you are checking for each of the ̀`nrow(df)` elements of `df$Lost.time` whether a specific condition is fulfilled. It therefore does not seem to make sense to have a single binary result as return value. The purpose of the function should be clarified before it is implemented.

An alternative to this function could be constructed in a one-liner with `ifelse`.

Comment: +1. But can you elaborate on point 3, the curly brackets around `else`? When I started working with R (and programming in general), I made the same mistake as the OP (i.e. not putting the brackets and `else` on the same line). However, I noticed that when I did it in a loop, it worked most of the time. But when it was a 'stand-alone' `else`-statement, it never worked. I did not thought of it for some time, but now I am curious how this is possible. Or should I make my own question with a reproducible example?

Comment: @Marcel10 Thanks for the feedback. Sorry I couldn't reply sooner - was away for a few days. I don't use `else` very often, and when I do I make sure that it follows the closing curly brace of the previous block on the same line. Not sure if this is an absolute necessity, but a "stand-alone" `else` *can* at least sometimes lead to problems. The recommendation to enclose `else` in curly braces is reported, e.g., in the "Curly Braces" section [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html) and [here](https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/collaboration.html#curly-braces). Hope this helps.

Comment: No worries, I found the answer in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37929184/if-else-does-the-line-break-between-and-else-really-matters):"R is an interpreted language, so R code is parsed line by line". . When the `if` and `else` statements are nested in a loop, R can identify them as one block of code. The 'stand-alone' `else` gives an error since it reads the `if` and  `else` statements separatly.

Comment: Thank you all ! it worked following the changes above, much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what you actually want to return in your function.  `return` can only be called once, after which it will return a single value and the function will terminate.

If you want to get a vector which will contain 1 or 0 depending on whether a given row in your data frame has `Lost.time > 0`, then the following one liner should do the trick:

```
x <- as.numeric(df$Lost.time > 0)
```

Comment: Looks like the OP is using {0,1} in place of {`FALSE`, `TRUE`} in the code snippet. Then, the call to `as.numeric` could be left out.

Comment: Thank you all ! it worked following the changes above, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If loops are used for writing a function indices should be used for each element.
Create a variable(x) in your dataframe, if the statements goes true it prints 1 else 0

```
LT = function(Lost.time) {
    for (i in 1:dim(df)) {
        if (as.numeric(df$Lost.time[i]) > 0) {
            df$x[i] <- 1
        }else{
          df$x[i] <- 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code won't work. Please test it before you post. For example, `x` is not initialized as a vector, so addressing `x[i]` won't work. Instead of `For` the loop should be written as `for`. The abandoned `else`statement will will lead to problems...

Comment: OK, that's better ;-)

Comment: @RHertel the for loop works fine on my test data.frame